# How can I reference an indexed property with CodeDOM?

Tags: c#, .net, codedom

How can I add index parameters to a reference to a property through CodeDom? With a CodeMethodInvokeExpression I am able attach a list of parameters:

```
CodeMethodInvokeExpression methodInvokeExpression = new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("myVariableName"), "SomeMethodName",parameters);
```

However I don't see anything about index properties with the CodePropertyReferenceExpression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the CodeIndexerExpression class.